# How to Index time-series based geospatial data

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures, database-indexes

I have the following use case: 5 billion+ geospatial data points, which need to be queried based on 3 predicate ranges: latitude, longitude, and date.   A bounding-box geospatial query usually returns 500K-1M rows, of which only about 0.4% are valid, once filtered by the date range.

The ideal structure for this is a 3D index: k-d tree/octree, etc, but PostGreSQL's (and most other databases) geospatial index is a 2D structure.  Does anyone have experience representing this type of query in a 3D index, perhaps as a point cloud, using the chronological value as 'Z' component?   (Note: even though the current environment is PostgreSQL, suggestions based on other engines are more than welcome)

EDIT: Another possibility I'm considering is reducing the date resolution to a discrete value rather than a range.  Then (in theory) I could use a DB product that flattens geospatial data into a standard B-Tree (using a tiling approach), and create a simple compound index, i.e. something along the lines of:

WHERE dateyear = 2015 AND location_tile = xxxxxxxxx

Comment: Spatially, your data is a prime candidate for the (PostGIS) `SP-GIST` index - especially if your spatial lookups follow a (binary or) quad tiling scheme, e.g. for common webmapping clients. However, if you receive strictly *consecutive* time series streams, and given your table size/ingestion rate, a classic `BRIN` index on the timestamp is a perfect match for time range lookups. A multi-column non-range index is heavy, especially with the wide distribution of 2D geometries plus highly granular timestamps. A mc-index on (and possibly clustered by) GeoHash and *date* could be worth a try.

Comment: Note that PostGIS supoorts `nD-GIST` indexing - so you _could_ convert your geometries to `POINT M` (having UNIX epoch timestamp as M value) and index `USING GIST(geom gist_geometry_ops_nd)` (and filter by `&&&`). It actually _may_ be a good candidate for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you don't really query on latitude and longitude, but using a geometrical query, like "overlaps with this bounding box" or "has not more than this distance from a certain point".

The best approach for this might be to use partitioning by date range. Then the date condition will lead to partition pruning, so you only have to perform a GiST index scan on those partitions that match the date condition. In addition, partitioning makes it easy to get rid of old data.

Comment: That approach would require >1000 partitions. I haven't experience with tables partitioned that fine-grained.  Do you expect that would negatively impact transactional performance?  Table is averaging nearly 2K/inserts/sec.

Comment: Gather more dates in a single partition. Partition pruning will still exclude most false positives.

Comment: Despite my comment above, this would also be my choice - avoiding heavy mc-colums and super-effective pruning. If I interpreted OPs spatial lookup correctly, it may be worth to partition by a fixed quad-tile count (i.e. by "zoom level" of a tiling scheme), and have a range index on the time columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can build multi-column GiST indexes.  With the help of the btree_gist extension and the postgis extension, you could make one GiST index over both the date and the geography, which would be more or less equivalent to an octree.  But it is hard to figure out what you actually have, a date, a date range, or some other aspect of the time dimension.

Comment: All 3 predicates are ranges, and it's my understanding that GIST indices are no different than a B-tree, in that only the first range predicate in a multi-column index is useful.  The example in my edit was based on my "flattening" the temporal and spatial aspects from a range to an equality predicate, so that a 1D tree index would work.

Comment: " it's my understanding that GIST indices are no different than a B-tree, in that only the first range predicate in a multi-column index is useful"  No, that's wrong.  GiST can use any of the columns.  Now it is beneficial if the column that is used most-selectively is first in the index, but that optimal placement is far less important than it is for B-tree.

Comment: So a 3-column GIST index actually uses a 3-dimensional tree structure, unlike a 3-colum B-tree index?  Well if so, that would be ideal.  Will try a test implementation and see how it performs.

Comment: @Endymio what solution have you used in the end? I have a very similar use case, the only difference I need to retrieve the most recent 1000 points within a certain bounding box.